# GATE: comparing Token.string to Macro

Tags: java, text-mining, gate

What I want, is comparing a 'Token.string' with a defined Macro.

What I tried:

```
Macro: ADDRESSING_NOUN
({Token.kind == word, Token.string ==~ "(?i)(sir|madam)"})

Rule: Name
(
  {Token.kind == word, Token.string !=~ ADDRESSING_NOUN}
)
```

Sadly this doesn't work.

So is there a way to compare them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question was answered by `Ian Roberts` via `Gate mailing list`.

his answer:

```
Template: addressing = "(?i)(sir|madam)"

Rule: Name
({Token.kind == word, Token.string !=~ [addressing]})
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the way you can use Macro inside Jape rules.

Macro are here to simplify the rules and are in fact replaced by there content at Jape compilation, for instance your should probably write something like:

```
Macro: ADDRESSING_NOUN
({Token.kind == word, Token.string ==~ "(?i)(sir|madam)"})

Rule: Name
(ADDRESSING_NOUN):name
```

And the rule that will be fired is

```
 ({Token.kind == word, Token.string ==~ "(?i)(sir|madam)"}):name
```